# Importing times from a txt file in c++

Tags: c++, fstream

I have this call log consisting of day time and duration data in a file:

Mo 12:30 16
Tu 7:15 10
We 9:10 20
Th 15:34 6
Fr 13:12 8

I want to store these data into variables so but i'm having trouble because of the colons.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
ifstream inputfile;
string day;
double time;
int hours;
string semicolon;
int minutes;
int timeSpent;

inputfile.open("Data.txt");
inputfile >> day;
cout << day << endl;
inputfile >> hours;
cout << hours << endl;
inputfile >> semicolon;
cout << semicolon << endl;
inputfile >> minutes;
cout << minutes << endl;
inputfile >> timeSpent;
cout << timeSpent << endl;



return 0;}
```

Comment: Treat the semicolon [as a character](http://cpp.sh/8kxa) not a string.

Answer (score 0):

C++11 has `get_time` and `put_time` for this, with a small tweak to your date format (at least three letters for days, hours and minutes must have leading zeros if less than 10) it's as easy as writing:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
  std::tm t;
  int duration;
  while (std::cin >> std::get_time(&t, "%a %R") >> duration)
    std::cout << std::put_time(&t, "%a %R") << ' ' << duration << '\n';
}
```

Your input would be as follows:

```
Mon 12:30 16 Tue 07:15 10 Wed 09:10 20 Thu 15:34 6 Fri 13:12 8
```